# Вопрос по квантификаторам в Java.

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Здравствуйте!
Разбираюсь с java, с квантификаторами...
Не могу понять как организовать некоторые ограничения.
Например такие:
количество числовых констант, в котором последовательно встречаются две одинаковые цифры

количество числовых констант длиннее n символов

На второй вопрос набросал:

```
regex = "\\d\\d\\d+" ;
s = "td tdfty 454 54855 ";
p2 = Pattern. compile (regex);
m2 = p2.matcher(s);
while(m2.find())
    System.out.println("2): " + m2.group());
```

Но увы, не на всех вариантах работает(
Помогите задать условия поиска.
Спасибо.

Comment: На первый вопрос во-вот нашел ответ: "\\d{n,}" вроде так. А на второй так и не смог.

Comment: Спасибо, а если нужно найти числовые константы со значением, например большим чем 120 то как быть? такое вроде не работает:(1+2+[1-9])*(1+[3-9]+[0-9])*([2-9]+[0-9]+[0-9])

Comment: @Alerr проще выдергивать трехзначные числа и сравнивать их с 120.

Answer (score 1):

регэксп \d{n,} указывает на любую числовую последовательность длиною n и более. Если вам нужны именно одинаковые цифры, то думаю тут надо использовать обратные ссылки и поиск будет не универсальным.

(\d)\1 - вроде так.